# unable to import json lib into GCP functions

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Added "json" in the requirment.txt but encountered below error. Works fine in local.
Any help on this please

Python version3.9

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement json (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for json; Error ID: 656dd225
```

Comment: You don't need to import JSON in your requirement in Python. Why are you doing that?

Comment: Yes, `json` is a part of `Python`, no need to add it in the requirements.txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as a community wiki to help other community members that can encounter this issue:

As stated by @guillaume blaquiere & @Mazlum Tosun:

You don't need to import JSON in your requirement in Python as `JSON` is a standard library in python so there's no need to install it.